# Completing my proof of exercise 1.6 in Jech - Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> **Theorem.** If $X$ is inductive, then so is the set $V = \{x\in X:x\text{ is transitive and every nonempty subset has an}\in\text{-minimal element}\}.$

*Proof (incomplete)*. Clearly $\emptyset\in V$, so let $x\in V$. I've already shown that $x\cup\{x\}\in X$ and is transitive, so I remain to show the $\in$-minimality property. Let $z\subset x\cup\{x\}$ be nonempty and note $x\in z$.* Suppose we could find $s\in z$ such that $s\in x$ - then $s\subset x$ by transitivity.

Have I started this exercise correctly? My main concern is that $x$ is not the right element to choose to show $\in$-minimality. If it is, then I'm still having trouble figuring out how to reach a contradiction from $s\subset x$. Hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $z \subset x \cup \{x\}$, there are two cases: $x \in z$ and $z \subset x$. The latter case is covered, as $x \in V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ z \subset x \cup \{ x \}$ be non empty.

Case 1: $ x \in x $:

Then $ x \cup \{ x \} = x $ and z has an $\in$-minimal element since $ x \in V $

Case 2: $ x \notin x $:

If $z=\{ x\}$ since $ x \notin x $, x is an $\in$-minimal element of z.

Otherwise $ z'= z \setminus \{ x\} \subset x$ is non empty.

Since  $ x \in V $ pick an $\in$-minimal element $p \in z' \subset x$. Remains to show $x \notin p$:

If $x \in p$ by transitivity $x \in x$. Contradiction.

Edit: Note that Case 1 cannot occur, since if $ x \in x$ then $z=\{x\}$ would be a nonempty subset of x without $\in$-minimal element.